# Why am I getting compile time errors in this C++ program?

Tags: programming, c++

I am new to Ubuntu and its terminal. I am trying to code C++ using `nano something.cpp` a general "Hello World" program at first.

First I got some error about `iostream.h` and `cout` not recognised. I searched the web and found that it was a newer C++ and we had to use `iostream` instead of `iostream.h` and `std::cout` instead of `cout`. It worked well after making those changes (compiled using gcc).

Now I tried creating the second program. Here I had to input my name and it would show "Hello Myname".

The code was:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  string g;
  std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
  std::cin >> g;
  std::cout << "Hello\n" << g << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile (using `gcc myprog.cpp -o hello`); I got the following errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:5:1: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:5:1: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stringfwd.h:65:33: note:   ‘std::string’
prog.cpp:5:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘g’
prog.cpp:7:13: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
```

I searched the web but did not find any help. How do I get rid of these errors?

I would also be happy if somebody would suggest me a book on this "NEWER" C++.

Comment: instead gcc use g++. It is not a newer C++ it is a C++ language, that you mistaken with C. C++ is compatibilie with C but it doesn't work in oposite direction. I would also suggest using Code:Blocks to begin C++ adventure in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

First of all use `g++` to compile, second you forgot the namespace qualifier for the string `g`. Try `std::string g;`. And compile it with `g++ myprog.cpp -o hello`.

Comment: Thank You very much....But the name which i am giving is coming in the next line after "Hello". Is there any way i can put it in same line??

Comment: Remove the `\n` character. Since `\n` stands for new line.